# MockMvc losing file during multipart call

Tags: mockmvc

I'm trying to test a file upload using MockMvc, here is the code snippet:

```
        final Map<String, String> boundary = new HashMap<>() {{ put("boundary", "1000000"); }};
        final MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("name", "name.ext", "multipart/form-data", "some data".getBytes());

        mockMvc.perform(
                multipart("/path/to/request")
                .file(file)
                .contentType(new MediaType("multipart", "form-data", boundary))
            ).andExpect(status().isOk())
```

The call goes through. The method processing the request has only one parameter - a `MultipartFile`. During a real execution, the method receives the file, no problem. However, when running the mock code above, the method always receives a null - the mock file is getting lost somewhere between the `perform(...)` and the actual method call.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the file name. It shouldn't be "name", it should have been "file", since this is what the caller was expecting.